# Reordering Custom Cell Causes the Constraints to get Messed Up

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a custom cell which has a reordering problem that looks like this:

[image: img]

Whenever I try to change the position of the cell, a weird thing happens, where the constraints break and half of the cell goes off screen then, when I exit editing mode, the cell diminishes into a small rectangle in the middle of the place where the cell used to be.

This is the console message which comes when I try to reorder a cell.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7cbe0 'Content View Leading to Shadow View Leading' H:|-(0)-[FriendZone.ShadowView:0x10512d210]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x105139d30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7cb90 'Content View Trailing to Shadow View Trailing' H:[FriendZone.ShadowView:0x10512d210]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x105139d30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7cb40 'Main Background Leading' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x105139fb0]   (active, names: '|':FriendZone.ShadowView:0x10512d210 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7caa0 'Main Background Trailing' H:[UIView:0x105139fb0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':FriendZone.ShadowView:0x10512d210 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7c8c0 'Stack View Center X' UIStackView:0x10513a190.centerX == UIView:0x105139fb0.centerX   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7c910 'Stack View Trailing' H:[UIStackView:0x10513a190]-(15)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x105139fb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7c780 'Time Width' UILabel:0x10513a880'9:48PM'.width <= 0.4*UIStackView:0x10513a190.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a79220 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x105139d30.width == 26.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283a7c780 'Time Width' UILabel:0x10513a880'9:48PM'.width <= 0.4*UIStackView:0x10513a190.width   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I tried searching for answers and debugging my constraints, but I still couldn't come up with a fix, let alone understand what's going on.

Here is the view hierarchy for the cell, along with its constraints.

[image: img]

And this is the custom class for the cell.

```
class PersonCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var mainBackground: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var shadowLayer: UIView!

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    }

    // To add left and right margins to tableViewCell and adjust gradientLayer's frame before the gradient is set
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += 5
            frame.size.width -= 2 * 5

            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your full layout, but first impression is that you have your stack view centered horizontally instead of constrained to Leading and Trailing. Try changing that... if it doesn't fix the issue, post your complete layout showing all the constraints.

Comment: @DonMag I tried it, but nothing changed. I added extra information about the views, constraints, and my custom cell class in my post.

Comment: The problem is definitely with how you are overriding the cell's `frame`. The frame is set repeatedly as you move the cell, and your override changes it on every call. If you comment-out that override func, the problem goes away. Not clear why you have that there to begin with?

Comment: Reordering works perfectly when I comment out the frame section, but the whole purpose of that code is to add left, right, top, and bottom margins to the cell. Now there is no spacing. Thank you for pointing out the problem. I'll try searching for another method to add margins. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just add margins with constraints? You have MainBackground and ShadowView each constrained without margins.